# ClassNotFoundException - android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to create a tab layout with swipeable views. To add `ViewPager` I have created `activity_fragments_logs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have added Support Library by following the steps at https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Now the design tab of this xml file is giving `ClassNotFoundException`. This is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompatFroyo
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:112)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:52)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:73)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat$FroyoViewConfigurationVersionImpl.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(ViewConfigurationCompat.java:56)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(ViewConfigurationCompat.java:105)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:367)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.<init>(ViewPager.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:379)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:401)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:333)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:674)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:663)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:663)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:790)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have read a similar question on Stack Overflow but that deals with Eclipse and I am using Android Studio.

[Updated SDK version, getting ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831019/updated-sdk-version-getting-classnotfoundexception-android-support-v4-view-vie)

I have searched a lot about this but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have included the Android support library on your app?

Comment: @Spotlight Android Studio told me to download support repository, I did that and now I can use its methods like `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`.

Comment: Have you added any 3rd party jar library in your project?

Comment: hey yo have to set your MainActivity extends FragmentActivity....hope this is the problem...

Comment: @NAP I have already done that in my class.

Comment: In the styles.xml file change the existing `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` which is the parent of the  _Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar_ , I read it somewhere , but do not know the reason for the error as I only started to learn android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30441307/784929

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

**Remove it from view pager it should be on the top of the hierarchy**

Comment: Make sure you have properly added the support v4 library properly(Right click on you project goto properties->java build path->oredr and export and then tick the android-support-v4.jar

Comment: There is no properties option in Android Studio. The above steps apply only to Eclipse.