# android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed (Android studio 1.2 + SDK pack) for the first time, I created a test project with demo tab activity. I have not written a single line of code, everything has been generated by Android Studio

In fragment_main.xml the following problem occurs.

[image]

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:127)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:84)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:84)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.createActionBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1691)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:362)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity(No code errors here but I am surprised to see calls of deprecated functions in a demo code):

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you just have installed SDK then it might have not loaded properly, try restarting your studio.

Comment: I restart and still get the same error

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Had the exact same problem. I got rid of it by changing `res/values/styles.xml` to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" to "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". So "Base." was missing...

Comment: Any idea why such a simple and obvious error occurs in Android Studio 1.2?

Literally just installed a JDK and Android Studio  1.2, "New Project" and made a blank empty activity and it shows me OP's ClassNotFoundException for ViewPropertyAnimatorListener. Any simple way to edit the defaults so that they don't do that?

Comment: This is such a bogus issue. If you are trying to run a "Hello world", it should just work. One shouldn't have to do googling just to do a hello world app. But anyway, thanks, pasql. This worked for me, too.

Comment: Thank  you @pasql, it works fine now, but I don't understand why. Can you explain me more?

Answer (score 17):

The Android Tools Project website lists this as a known bug of version 1.2 of the Android Gradle plugin, and declare it will be fixed by version 1.2.3

See:
http://tools.android.com/knownissues

They propose 3 workarounds:

Quote the above link:

> Workaround 1: First manually build the project, then manually sync the
>   project (using the Sync with Gradle files in the toolbar, or from the
>   Tools > Android menu), then finally press Refresh in the toolbar above
>   the layout editor.
>
> Workaround 2: Switch the Android Gradle plugin from 1.2.x to 1.1.3 for
>   now. When 1.2.3 is released you can switch back to the 1.2.x versions.
>
> Workaround 3: If the above workarounds don't work for you, and you are
>   on windows, please try downloading a build from [link in website]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I think it's an issue while rendering AppCompatTheme.

to enable preview again switch to a stock theme like "Material Light" / "Material.Light.DarkActionBarTheme"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. The solution was:

- First you have to Sync your project.
- Next, go to Build menu, and clic    on the Clean Project.
- Finally, again, go to Build menu, and clic on    the Rebuild option.

No need to change a thing, and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I used `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">`in my styles.xml and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error from an absolutely new project, created by Android Studio 1.2.

@florent's solution worked for me:

> switch to a stock theme like "Material Light" / "Material.Light.DarkActionBarTheme"

Changed this, built the project, and the render started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing the values under: Relative Layout -> Properties -> Padding | to numeric values instead of default value. Then hit Rebuild.

Comment: Can you add some more explanation what you just did?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to use the latest gradle version

Answer (score 0):

by changing `res/values/styles.xml` to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

do `DarkActionBarTheme` or
    `NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio 3.0**

On the right-top side, you can see `AppTheme`. 
Click on it, from the dropdown choose 'Material Light' or something other than default.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. It is some rendering issue with the AppCompat themes. So I made changes to the styles.xml file as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent ="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

So the issue resolved.However if we still want to use the AppCompat themes, what should be done, I have not yet found out.

Comment: Hi SabU , welcome to stackoverflow.   looks like you've had some problem with formatting the post  as you are missing crucial information in your post.  you can use the graphical editor to mark code (select the code and use the {} button above  or use the markup here :http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting