# Not showing user interface. Means no layout ,buttons

Tags: android

My friend give me this project and when I open this project, it's not showing a thing.
[image]

Comment: You see the drop down with android icon that has 27 next to it? change that to 26 and see if it renders.
If not, clear android cache and restart

Comment: How to clear Android cache

Comment: file->invalidate caches/restart->invalidate, then Build->clean and finally Build->rebuild.

Comment: still not working

Comment: I can't think of anything else, maybe check help>updates to see if there is an update?

Answer (score 0):

Check this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993270/9370917

You need change the parent theme from the styles.xml file