# No connection to web service .net with Android Emulator

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have a problem,when debug, Observe the output in Logcat window :

```
KSoap2 - Error : Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method...
```

I used ksoap2 API to connect with web service which is wrote by asp.net.
When i use SDK & ADT 16 , everything is good, no problem but with SDK & ADT 17 have many problems

what do i do to connect web service using SDK,ADT 17 & Ksoap2 API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9824539/1012284

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the jar file into the assets file of your project in the workspace of eclipse and tick the check box at the Order and Export in the java build path page.