# Android Couldn't find classes after update SDK. What can I do?

Tags: android, class, sdk, find

I have a big big problem.

Yesterday I updated the Android SDK and, since then, I no longer run correctly my application on my device or emulator.

Eclipse does not have any kind of error, but when I start the application there are some errors such as:

```
 03-26 14:06:58.900: E / AndroidRuntime (32593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo com.example {}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # 7: Error inflating class com . viewpager.TitlePageIndicator

 03-26 14:06:58.900: E / AndroidRuntime (32593): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # 7: Error inflating class com.viewpager.TitlePageIndicator

 03-26 14:06:58.900: E / AndroidRuntime (32 593): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.viewpager.TitlePageIndicator in loader
```

How do I do? It 's very important for me to solve this error!

**I also noticed that the apk is smaller than when the application worked.**

I tried to uninstall everything (jdk, sdk, eclipse) and reinstall and today I tried also to format and reinstall windows.

Please Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android-SDK r17 ruins working projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824491/android-sdk-r17-ruins-working-projects)

Comment: format and reinstall Windows is the correct way to go...just kidding

Comment: @Meroelyth My guess is there is problem in package name..Go to error showing XML where you given this lines com.viewpager.TitlePageIndicator and check package name is correct.. where you have the supporting file..

Comment: "com . viewpager" << You have extra space in the class path for this view in one of your XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that occurs after the migration to ADT R17.

You can find a detailed memo from Xavier Ducrohet on Google+ :
https://plus.google.com/u/0/109385828142935151413/posts

Basic steps to solve this issue are :

- Remove the libraries from the standard Java build path :
  Right click on the project name > Properties > Java Build Path > tab Libraries > remove everything except the “Android X.X” (2.3.3 in my case) and the “Android Dependencies”
- Rename the libraries folder from “lib” to “libs”
  By doing that, all the libraries in the folder “libs” are found by the Android plugin and are added to the “Android Dependencies” item of the project

If you have references to jars that are not in the ‘libs’ folder, for example if you use ‘classpath variable’, you can resolve the NoClassDefFoundError issue with the new ADT 17 by exporting the references.

To export the references: simply go to “Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was because because of the eclipse project.
To solve it I created a new project in eclipse, copy my existing project classes and resources into it and then launched eclipse again and added my custom includes.