# JSoup is not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to delete html tags from a string using JSoup, but at run time the emulator gives an exception that is: NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.JSoup

here is my code:

```
String result="<html> hello </html>";
Jsoup.parse(result).text();
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: you are missing a dependency.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean Dave ?

Comment: In what folder you put jsoup lib?

Comment: I put it in a folder with name lib in the project folder and configured the build path and included it

Comment: Try cleaning and bulding your project and run again. If that didn work then restart eclipse and then try again.

Comment: I did that, it did not work , :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting JSoup jar in lib, put it in libs.

Try [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934744/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-jsoup-jsoup) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android/9916751#9916751)..,.

Comment: Yeah, Android Dev plugin expects "libs" folder... if you create something w different name, it wont pick it up...