# "Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup" adding jar to /libs doesn't work?

Tags: android, jsoup, noclassdeffounderror

I'm having the exact problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934744/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-jsoup-jsoup).
I followed the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android/9916751#9916751).
I have added the jsoup jar to the \libs folder but it just still won't work. Tried loads of different stuff like deleting the jar and re-downloading but nothing has worked? At a loss at what else I can do?

Comment: You could try to move up the jar file in "Order and Export". Right click on the project -> properties -> Java build path -> Order and Export.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in this question. So that this question is independent of the other one.

Comment: We have no idea what you can do, because we don't really know what you did. We don't even know how you're building it.

Comment: The Jar for jsoup does not appear in the 'Order and Export' tab?

Comment: The problem is that when I run my android application and click the button that triggers the jsoup component it crashes. The error is as described in the title. I am using the latest version of everything like eclipse ADT, R17 and jsoup 1.7.2.  Can't post my code right now as I'm posting from my phone but I know there is no problem with the jsoup component because it runs fine as a standalone application in Java SE.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)
Basically just needed to tick the got to the 'Order and Export' tab and check 'Android Private Libraries'

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You cant use Jsoup functions in the on-create of Activity. You need to make either Async Task or thread.

This is to prevent doing blocking tasks in you activity.

Here is a nice blog that explain how to do it and provide sample code as well.

[Sample Code Click here](http://ickool2004.blogspot.com/2013/10/web-scrapping-in-android-using-jsoup.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put `Jsoup.jar` both in the AP and ACP. In both projects it should reside in `libs`, imported as jar by eclipse. Clean the project and it will work.

I had a similar problem, with this context:

- Android Project (doesn't need itself jsoup)
- Android Class Project (needing jsoup)
- Jsoup.jar

I've imported the ACP in AP, with all classes, but it seems to won't recognize `jsoup`, that was needed to prevent errors during compilation.