# Not being able to get data from website

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have run into a problem in my Android application where I could not get specific data from a website.  My app just crashes.  Here is my code:

```
    private void AddListenerOnButton() {
    spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            //WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {          
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
                    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.example.currencyconverter.Fragment2$1.onItemSelected(Fragment2.java:77)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-09 23:04:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is happening here? I can't seem to understand what is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the clue...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
```

Your application can not find the Jsoup libraries when it runs. Unfortunately I can tell you why with what I can see, but here's a link that has many good reasons and fixes...

[Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934744/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-jsoup-jsoup)