# How to download HTML source of an Instagram page

Tags: android, instagram

in my app i need to download HTML source of an Instagram profile and parse it to get some information (media and followed-by count).
That's my code (it works for all sites i tested, except for Instagram):

```
try {
            InputStream in;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                throw new NoConnectionException("not instanceof http");

            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            in = httpConn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            String source = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                source += line;
            br.close();
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

When i debug it with LogCat, String source is empty.

Comment: First of all "put httpclinet away and use Retrofit or Volley"

Comment: @sadeghsaati Where do you see `HttpClient` here?

Comment: Maybe you retrieve an Exception? Your catch block is emtpy, so it may be fail-silent.

Comment: @Henry Sorry I meant HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 2):

Use Jsoup for HTML parsing. It is quite easy and handy.
Take start from this answer and follow documents [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24346393/5275639)

Comment: Ok, but why my code works with all sites i tested, and doesn't work with Instagram?

Comment: You code looks fine too. But Jsoup is very simple. Just one line code and you have all HTML. Try that. I have done that its simple