# OData class not found when trying to access SQL Azure database

Tags: android, odata, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create an android application to connect to Azure's SQL database. When I try to create a ODataConsumer object that would later be used to filter the message.

The ODataConsumer object is create with the create method

```
ODataConsumer c = ODataConsumer.create("http:/xxx/yyy.svc");
```

But when the execution reaches here, I get class def not found exception and the application is force closed.

I downloaded the jar files from the following site

http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/downloads/list

I started off with v0.3 as this is the jar file used in the demo that is provided by Microsoft. I also tried v0.4

I add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the manifest file of the project. I also import 
    `import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumer;
    import org.odata4j.core.OEntity;.`

Am I missing something here?

The error that I get is `AndroidRuntime(595): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.data4j.consumer.OdataConsumer`

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using the latest version.

Also the class name in the error is misspelled.  It's ODataConsumer not OdataConsumer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. In my case I was able to follow the example here:

http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/

which is described here:

[Android-SDK r17 ruins working projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824491/android-sdk-r17-ruins-working-projects)

which solved my problem. Good luck.